# Plot multiple shapefile over multiple raster

Tags: r, plot, raster, shapefile, levelplot

i am trying to plot same shapefile over multiple raster plot using the code below:

```
ras <- list.files("filepath", pattern = "\\.tif$", full=TRUE)
s <- stack(ras)
plot(s)
plot(world, add=TRUE)
```

Unfortunately, adding shapefile 'world' using the code below doesn't seem to work.

```
plot(world, add=TRUE)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used to plot lots of rasters, and would plot data points, and overlay a map of the world to visualize my results.

I would plot my points first, and then add the map.  This sounds like what you want to do

I did not use the plot command twice though.  I would try

```
plot(s)
map(region="world", add=T)
```

Because I don't have access to your data, I cannot test this myself

Comment: is 'map' a part of script or your shapefile? as i am getting error 'Error in map(region = "world", add = T) : could not find function "map". I want to add the shapefile of the world and not the map from R.

Comment: I had the following packages open when I am doing this:

library(raster)
library(maps)
library(magick)
library(rgdal)

I would guess it's in the "maps" package

Comment: i want to overlay a shapefile instead of calling a world region function 'map' from R